# Stripe integration is giving an error in views.py

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

my stripe integration code in the views.py code is following:

```
def checkoutsession(request):
   try:
      checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
          line_items=[
              {
                   
               'price': '20',
               'quantity': 1,
              },

              ],
          mode='payment',
          success_url='http://localhost:3000' + '/success.html',
          cancel_url='http://localhost:3000' + '/cancel.html',

          )
   except Exception as e:
        return str(e)

    return HttpResponse(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

The error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

the HTML code is following:

```
{% extends 'basic.html' %}
{% block body %}
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


<section>
  <div>

<div>
  <h3>Pay</h3>
  <h5>$20.00</h5>
</div>
</div>
<form action="/checkoutsession" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}

    <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
  </form>
 </section>
{% endblock body %}
```

I am integrating a sandbox payment gateway. The frontend is displaying correctly , but the backend is problematic.I am using django framework.

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared is creating a Checkout Session but passing `price: '20'` when that API expects a real Price id `price_123` that you would have created in your Stripe account first. You can read more about this in Stripe's docs [here](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/how-products-and-prices-work) for example.

Because you pass an integer, the API is going to respond with a clear error saying this can't work but your Python code isn't properly returning the error here because of `return str(e)` which likely doesn't work. You should look at Stripe's docs around error handling for Python [here](https://stripe.com/docs/error-handling?lang=python) and for example switch to `return e.message` instead.

Finally, as a developer, make sure to look at the request logs in your Stripe Dashboard as they will often have the most recent error and help you debug things quickly [here](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs).